# How to get SimpleFeatureStore from OgrDataStore?

Tags: geotools

we want to create a SimpleFeatureStore for modify features but not successful. we have used the following code:-

```
OGRDataStoreFactory factory = new JniOGRDataStoreFactory();       
          Map<String, String> connectionParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
          connectionParams.put("DriverName", "MapInfo File");
          connectionParams.put("DatasourceName", "C:\\Users\\User\\1\\test.TAB");
          DataStore store =(DataStore) factory.createDataStore(connectionParams);
          SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource("test");
          SimpleFeatureType schema = featureSource.getSchema();
          SimpleFeatureCollection fc = featureSource.getFeatures();

          SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
```

It gives us an error.

---

org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRFeatureSource cannot be cast to org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply GeoTools' way of saying that your datastore is not writable.

Why it isn't writable could be for a number of reasons:

1. your file is readonly
2. you lack permission to write to the file
3. you are using a pre 2.0 version of GDAL/OGR which can't write tab files.

Comment: thanks @iant the work has done by changing the GDAL/OGR version from 1.1.1 to 2.0.1 .
But one more thing we have to update one column value depends on the other column. For example if we have Two Attributes:-  Attribute1 and Attribute2 , we want to update Attribute2 = (Attribute1+10) how it will possible using `ModifyFeatures` ?

Comment: Get the attribute and calculate the new value before modify features